# é possivel trabalhar com arquivos shp em delphi?

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de montar uma aplicação que teria a função de um GIS (QGIS por exemplo), que ao invés que desenvolver um *plugin* que dependa dele do software para funcionar, gerar em `Delphi` um executável independente.

Já possuo um *script* semelhante feio em `R` e `Python.`
O `Qgis` abre o contorno do mapa, e a pessoa abre o *script* e gera alguns pontos com base em um calculo geoestatistico.

Então a principio as funções iniciais deveriam ser algo como ler o arquivo `shp` poligonizado e mostrar na tela, e a partir disso gerar os pontos levando em consideração as condições do mapa.

Acho que isso dependeria de alguma biblioteca, não consegui encontrar exemplo, existem? É possível?

Comment: só uma duvida .shp é o formato Shapefile shape ou AutoCad?

Comment: o formato .shp que pode ser feito em auto cad, gps e outros...

Comment: Para começarmos, e estou interessado em te ajudar rsrsrsrs,edite a pergunta e poste um parte do arquivo, e se possível informe o que você deseja com esses dados, se vai guardar em base de dados, etc, Se eu não encontrar algo que de para adaptar para você, vamos desenvolver do Zero uma solução, claro que as informações que pedi é crucial para tal abordagem!

Comment: Ok, vou reformular a pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amigo, a pesquisa foi grande e obtive grandes resultados!

Hoje já existe soluções para isto, então analisei varias e varias e acabei encontrando diversas soluções, porem, você precisara de um esforço maior para chegar no nível que você deseja!

Atualmente os arquivos não estão resumidos apenas em `.SHP`, atualizados hoje:

```
SHP: The graphical data
SHX: The index
DBF: Attribute data
```

A solução mais facil hoje é a biblioteca [ShapeLib](http://www.triplexware.huckfinn.de/shpapi.html) (`ShpAPI129.pas` & `shapelib.dll`).

Funcional para o *Delphi 7*, você encontrara algum problema em algumas de suas funções, principalmente na hora de abrir os arquivos, mas já vou passar a dica!

Não tenho certeza da versão do Delphi em diante que foi modificado, mas garanto que da *Delphi 2009* em diante o Default é `Unicode characters`, portanto, nas funções de chamada da biblioteca você precisa mudar:

```
Function SHPOpen (pszShapeFile: PChar; pszAccess: PChar): SHPHandle; cdecl; external LibName name '_SHPOpen';

//para:

Function SHPOpen (pszShapeFile: PAnsiChar; pszAccess: PAnsiChar): SHPHandle; cdecl; external LibName name '_SHPOpen';


//observe a mudança do PChar para PAnsiChar
```

Se não realizar a mudança citada acima, o retorno da função será `nil`.
Na versão *Delphi 7* funciona sem a conversão!

Aqui um projeto parado, mas que ainda esta disponível varias ferramentas e exemplos: [CartoVCL](http://cartovcl.com/wp/code-samples/#shape-file-style-override)

Em Inglês, mas super útil para aumentar o conhecimento: [Delphi Gis Wiki](http://giswiki.org/wiki/Delphi)

Tópico abandonado de um fórum sobre o assunto: [PointInShapefile and shape fill with Delphi](http://www.mapwindow.org/phorum/read.php?3,5344,10117)

Comment: Muito bacana, era a informação que eu precisa para começar a trabalhar, muito obrigado.